# Dynamic determination of snakemake wildcard fails

Tags: snakemake

I have a short question regarding dynamic determination of wildcards in snakemake. In the code posted below a RNAseq read with a given id is downloaded (download_reads). The download either yields a ".sra" or ".sralite" file, which is why I declare the output to be dynamic with {ext} to be determined after the rule is completed. In the next rule (fq_dump) .fastq files are extracted from the .sra/.sralite file. Depending on how the RNAseq experiment was conducted (single or paired reads) this creates 1 file ({rsa_id}.fastq) or 2 files ({rsa_id}_1.fastq and {rsa_id}_2.fastq). For the sra files this seem to work fine, but for the {outfiles} wildcard snakemake gives the following error: `Wildcards in input files cannot be determined from output files: outfiles`

Now I managed work around the issue by just renaming the {rsa_id}.fastq file to {rsa_id}_1.fastq in case its a single read and then checking in the map_reads rule whether {rsa_id}_2.fastq also exists but I would be really interested in finding out why the dynamic determination of the wildcard works in one but not the other case. Would be grateful for any input :)

```py
rule map_reads:
    input:
        fastq=dynamic("/data/gpfs-1/users/endresn_c/scratch/NE38/data/reads/{rsa_id}/fastq/{outfiles}"),
        genome=lambda wildcards: f"data/genomes/{accessions.loc[wildcards.rsa_id, 'genome_id']}/index/Genome"
    output:
        "data/alignments/{rsa_id}/{rsa_id}_ReadsPerGene.out.tab"
    threads: 20
    resources:
        mem_mb_per_cpu=1024*4, 
        runtime=60*4
    run:
        readFilesIn = " ".join(input.fastq)
        shell(rf"""
        readDir=data/reads/{wildcards.rsa_id}
        genomeDir={os.path.dirname(input["genome"])}
        mkdir -p data/alignments/{wildcards.rsa_id}/

        STAR --runThreadN {threads} --genomeDir $genomeDir \
        --readFilesIn {readFilesIn} \
        --outFileNamePrefix data/alignments/{wildcards.rsa_id}/{wildcards.rsa_id}_ \
        --outSAMtype BAM SortedByCoordinate \
        --quantMode GeneCounts
        rm -rf {readFilesIn}
        """) 



rule fq_dump:
    input:
        dynamic("/data/gpfs-1/users/endresn_c/scratch/NE38/data/reads/{rsa_id}/{rsa_id}/{rsa_id}.{ext}")
    output:
        dynamic("/data/gpfs-1/users/endresn_c/scratch/NE38/data/reads/{rsa_id}/fastq/{outfiles}")
    resources:
        mem_mb=1024*4,
        disk_mb=1024*50,
        runtime=60*4
    run:
        print(output[0])
        shell(rf"""
        fasterq-dump -p -O {os.path.dirname(output[0])} {input[0]}
        """)
        

rule download_reads:
    output:
        dynamic("/data/gpfs-1/users/endresn_c/scratch/NE38/data/reads/{rsa_id}/{rsa_id}/{rsa_id}.{ext}")
    resources:
        mem_mb=1024*4,
        disk_mb=1024*4, 
        runtime=60*6
    run:
        read_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(output[0]),"..")
        sra_id = wildcards.rsa_id
        shell(fr"""
        mkdir -p {read_dir}
        prefetch -O {read_dir} {sra_id}

        """)
```